# Examples of non-semisimple algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-algebras

I've seen the following definition of semisimple algebra:

An algebra X is said to be semisimple if $\bigcap \{M \subset X : M \text{ is a maximal ideal}\} = \{0\}$.

But I couldn't find any examples of non-semisimple algebras in this context.

Comment: $k[x]/(x^2)$ where $k$ is a field.

Answer (score 4):

Take an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with complex entries. $(n>1)$.

Consider the collection of matrices obtained as the linear combination of all its powers $A^k, k\ge0$. (Cayley-Hamilton theorem assures us that we will not lose anything  if we restrict ourselves upto $n$-th power.)

This is a subalgebra of matrix algebra. This subalgebra will be semisimple iff the chosen  matrix $A$ is diagonalizable. (Actually this will be a commutative subalgebra).

(So  diagonalizable matrices  are also called semisimple matrices.)